# TwiiterSearch displaying errors in new installation

Tags: python, twitter-search

I am new to TwitterSearch from GitHub [TwitterSearch](https://github.com/ckoepp/TwitterSearch) and when I'm trying some of the provided samples, I get the following errors:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "test.py", line 1, in 
>       from TwitterSearch import *
>     File "/home/pi/Downloads/TwitterSearch-master/TwitterSearch/TwitterSearch.py", line 5, in 
>       from .TwitterSearchException import TwitterSearchException
>   ValueError: Attempted relative import in non-package

and when I do a suggested edit to TwitterSearch: "from TwitterSearch.TwitterSearchException import TwitterSearchException" I get this error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "test.py", line 1, in 
>       from TwitterSearch import *
>     File "/home/pi/Downloads/TwitterSearch-master/TwitterSearch/TwitterSearch.py", line 5, in 
>       from TwitterSearch.TwitterSearchException import TwitterSearchException
>   ImportError: No module named TwitterSearchException

The program I am using is:

```html
from TwitterSearch import *


try:
    tuo = TwitterUserOrder('myusername')

    ts = TwitterSearch(
            consumer_key = '',
            consumer_secret = '',
            access_token = '',
            access_token_secret = ''
        )


    for tweet in ts.search_tweets_iterable(tuo):
        print( '@%s tweeted: %s' % ( tweet['user']['screen_name'], tweet['text'] ) )

except TwitterSearchException as e: # catch all those ugly errors
    print(e)
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: can you run this:
pip list

And see if you have installed TwitterSearch

Comment: Yes: TwitterSearch (1.0.1)

Comment: I have tested in my env.  It works, probably you have screwed up in installation process.  I would recommend creating new virtual env and install there and try to run it.

Comment: I'm getting a different error, but it looks like that was the issue.